# How to use a different version of conda inside an environment

Tags: ubuntu, version, conda, virtual, environment

I want to use an older version of conda than the actual I have installed (4.9.2) because of some compatibility issues with older versions of packages, and I would like to install it inside a conda environment, still maintaining the newer version of conda in my system. I would prefer not to install the older version outside the environment because, in that case, I should install a different version of python on my system too.

I run on the bash

```
conda create old_conda python=3.6 conda=4.6
```

But then, if I enter the environment by

```
conda activate old_conda
```

and type

```
conda -V
```

I get

```
conda 4.9.2
```

which is the actual version installed in my system.

Instead, inside `old_conda` environment, I would like to use the version of conda that I installed in it to install other packages that, otherwise, would throw an error.+

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: What packages do you have that throw an error?

Comment: @FlyingTeller These packages with these versions: menpo=0.8.1 menpofit=0.4.1 menpodetect=0.4.0

Comment: Instead of trying to get an old conda version, try to set `-c free` when trying to install them